# FastApi returns "field required" and "value_error.missing" for one of my parameters, but the field is there

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I do a Post with some parameters, but one of them returns "field required" and "value_error.missing", but the field is there and it has a value. See the output of Postman.
[image: field "body" is not missing]

In schemas.py the fields are defined as follows:

```
class Message(BaseModel):
    title: str
    id: int
    datim: Optional[datetime]
    to_id: Optional[int]
    from_id: Optional[int]
    body: Optional[str]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

So why does it complain about 'body'?

Comment: Are you positive that model is the one that's being used here? It has the body as optional so it shouldn't trigger an error even if it is missing.

Comment: Yes, I  noted that too. I also tried without optional, to no avail. I do not have another pydantic model for 'Message' . It looks like something is 'stuck' here

Comment: Can you share the code for your route itself?

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer?

Comment: I encountered the same error when I erroneously defined a field that mismatched between my Pydantic 'model' and my SQLAlchemy 'model'

Answer (score 9):

It turned out I had an extra argument in my function for `@app.post()` that was not used.

Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

This is for anyone who still has issues with this, I had a one to one relationship but had not specified `uselist=False` while defining the relationship.